# Oracle alter session (internal buffer)

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to set the next date and time format for the next session, something like this:

```
alter session set nls_date_format='"Madrid day "DD" of "month" of "YYYY" time: "HH:MI"';
```

But I get the error: "ORA-01801 date format is too long for internal buffer" ...
Is there any other way to apply this format?

Comment: Why are you trying to set it at session level; to override the settings from any clients, while not having to explicitly specify the mask in each `to_char()` call? Are you always running the subsequent queries in a particular client? There may be ways to make specifying the common format less long-winded. (Are you overriding `nls_date_language` too?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nls_date_format is not intended for such a verbose use, and you must consider that it apply also to coversion from char to date. It's a tool for addressing i18n/l10n, not for user output formatting.